# Redis - performance

Tags: redis

I doing some performance tests for Redis which is run in docker with some resource limits. I using memtier benchmar for those tests. I have noticed that for a message size of 10kB, I get better ops/sec performance than for a message with a size of 5kB. I give you the plot below which presents the results. Can someone explain to me why there is such a situation?  [image]

Comment: on X there is a connection number per thread and on Y there is Ops/sec

Comment: You ran some code we can't see on a machine and OS you didn't specify and you'd like us to help interpret the results? If you'd like someone to help you, it often helps to make it easy for them...